# Wrong fit when using k nearest neighbors regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, knn, nearest-neighbor

I use the nearest neighbors method to predict the price of a stock. I have raw data in example.txt file. I use the close column (price at the end of the period = 1 minute). Linear regression predicts well (shown in green). But the method of nearest neighbors works only at the beginning and then turns into a straight line, please tell me how to fix this? Here is my code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor


class Reader:

def __init__(self, filename='example.txt'):
    self.filename = filename

def read(self):
    try:
        file = open(self.filename)
        return file.read()
    except IOError:
        return "File not found"

def main():
    x = Reader('example.txt')
    print(x.read())


class Regression:

def __init__(self, window, P0, Ptest, i):
    self.window = window
    self.P0 = P0
    self.Ptest = Ptest
    self.i = i
    self.data_train = self.get_data_train()
    self.x_train = self.get_x_train()
    self.y_train = self.get_y_train()
    self.data_test = self.get_data_test()
    self.x_test = self.get_x_test()
    self.y_test = self.get_y_test()

def get_data_train(self):
    """ Method of obtaining data train on prices for the entire period."""
    x = Reader('example.txt')
    data = x.read().splitlines()
    close_column = [x.split(',')[7] for x in data][1:]
    result = [float(item) for item in close_column]
    relative_price = result[:int(len(result)*P0)]
    return relative_price

def get_data_test(self):
    """ Method of obtaining data test on prices for the entire period."""
    x = Reader('example.txt')
    data = x.read().splitlines()
    close_column = [x.split(',')[7] for x in data][1:]
    result = [float(item) for item in close_column]
    len_x_test = int(len(result) * Ptest)
    len_x_train = int(len(result) * P0)
    relative_price = result[(len_x_train + (len_x_test * self.i)): len_x_train + len_x_test 
    * (self.i + 1)]
    return relative_price

def get_x_train(self):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(self.data_train)):
        if i + self.window < len(self.data_train):
            x.append(self.data_train[i: i + self.window])
    return x

def get_y_train(self):
    y = []
    for i in self.data_train[self.window:]:
        y += [i]
    return y

def get_x_test(self):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(self.data_test)):
        if i + self.window < len(self.data_test):
            x.append(self.data_test[i: i + self.window])
    return x

def get_y_test(self):
    y = []
    for i in self.data_test[self.window:]:
        y += [i]
    return y


class Linear_regression(Regression):

    def callculate(self):
    reg_linear = LinearRegression().fit(self.x_train, self.y_train)
    y_pred = reg_linear.predict(self.x_test)
    return y_pred


class Nearest_neighbor(Regression):

    def callculate(self):
    reg_neighbor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=window, weights='distance')
    reg_neighbor.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train)
    y_pred = reg_neighbor.predict(self.x_test)
    return y_pred

window = 10
Pk = 1
P0 = 0.1
Ptest = 0.01
k = (Pk - P0)/Ptest
i = 0
y_real = []
y_neigh = []
y_lin = []
while i < k:
    lin_price = list(Linear_regression(window, P0, Ptest, i).callculate())
    neighbor = list(Nearest_neighbor(window, P0, Ptest, i).callculate())
    y_neigh.extend(neighbor)
    y_lin.extend(lin_price)
    y_real.extend(list(Linear_regression(window, P0, Ptest, i).y_test))
    i += 1

""" Output to graphs of the received data """

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y_real, label='Initial data')
ax.plot(y_neigh, label='Nearest Neighbor Data')
ax.plot(y_lin, label='Linear Regression Data')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (min)')
ax.set_ylabel('Price, ($)')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: The resulting graph]

[image: The resulting graph(increased)]

[image: Data in file example.txt]

Answer (score 0):

> *"Linear regression predicts well"*

No, it never predicted well. You just looked at the graph and thought it looked  kind of similar. But if you look more closely, your 'model' simply takes the price of a bit ago as the prediction of the price now. That means, it's not *predicting* anything! It's a history device, not a prediction device.

That's why if you feed back this sort of 'model' into itself you get a straight line: it always predicts the next price is going to be equal to the last one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Can you tell me? Is it possible to make a prediction similar to real data?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Markets are generally unpredictable. Any patterns that do exist are quickly stamped out by people with more money, knowledge, resources and computational power than you.